# FindMatchingFiles can't find some files or they have not been downloaded

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to find a file called GlobalAssemblyInfo.vb using FindMatchingFiles activity and the expression:

```
String.Format("{0}\**\GlobalAssemblyInfo.vb", buildDirectory)
```

However, it can't find anything. I tried adding a new FindMatchingFiles activity searching for all VB files and created a loop to write the items to the build output, however some of the directories are not displayed.

So, does this workflow begins only when the source has been downloaded? Or is this a parallel task?

PS: I'm creating a workflow derived from UpgradeTemplate.xaml

Comment: why do you want to find the file, try the SourcesDirectory for 'unbuilt' code, try the BinariesDirectory for 'compiled' code

Comment: I've found that the build definition is not downloading the mapped folder entirely. What can I do to fix this? I have 3 solutions in one of the directories, is there any problem with this?

Comment: 3 solutions wouldn't be an issue, are your source control settings covering all of the folders you require?

Comment: The directories I require are all sub-directories of the mapped folder set in Source Settings.

Comment: The mapped folder contains many files (on dev machine it takes several minutes to download it), so a good question is: will the workflow begin only when the files has been downloaded?

Comment: no, but yes. the workflow will begin, amd one of the first things it does is to download the source, when the download is complete it will move to the next activity in the workflow

Comment: I've deleted the src folder on the build server manually and found that the activity that causes the src to download is not running until I get an exception. What activity should I use to download the files beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the sources are downloaded later in the workflow and I needed the file in the beginning, I've used a DownloadFiles activity and now I got it working. Thanks!